# Calendário dinâmico de meses JavaScript

Tags: javascript

sou iniciante em Javascript.

Preciso fazer um calendário que mostra apenas os meses.

Por exemplo:

Estamos em Setembro.
O calendário vai mostrar de Setembro(2016) a Agosto(2017).

Com o código abaixo, eu consigo imprimir os meses de Janeiro a Dezembro.
Mas preciso que ele mostre do mês atual até 12 meses à frente.
Podem me ajudar?

```js
            window.onload = function calendar() {
                var a = new Date();
                var b = a.getMonth();
                var months = [
                    "Janeiro",
                    "Fevereiro",
                    "Março",
                    "Abril",
                    "Maio",
                    "Junho",
                    "Julho",
                    "Agosto",
                    "Setembro",
                    "Outubro",
                    "Novembro",
                    "Dezembro"
                ];
                var i = months[i];
                for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("month-time")[i].innerHTML = months[i];
                }
            }
```

Comment: Só ví agora essas duas variáveis desnecessárias no começo da função.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
var a = new Date();
var b = a.getMonth();
var months = [
    "Janeiro",
    "Fevereiro",
    "Março",
    "Abril",
    "Maio",
    "Junho",
    "Julho",
    "Agosto",
    "Setembro",
    "Outubro",
    "Novembro",
    "Dezembro"
];
window.onload = function calendar() {
    var meses = [];
    for (i = b; i <= b + 11; i++) {
        var mes = i > 11 ? months[i - 12] : months[i];
        meses.push(mes);
    }
    [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("month-time"), function(el, i) {
        el.innerHTML = meses[i];
    })
}
```

```css
.month-time:first-of-type {color: blue;}
```

```html
<div class="month-time"></div>
<div class="month-time"></div>
<div class="month-time"></div>
<div class="month-time"></div>
<div class="month-time"></div>
<div class="month-time"></div>
<div class="month-time"></div>
<div class="month-time"></div>
<div class="month-time"></div>
<div class="month-time"></div>
<div class="month-time"></div>
<div class="month-time"></div>
```

Dessa maneira crias a array num loop e depois chamas todos os elementos de uma só vêz e iteras preenchendo-os com o mês correto

Comment: Funcionou direitinho! Muito obrigado!